# The most optimised MySQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, syntax

While I've searched the web a lot I haven't quite found the answer yet. In PHP you can optimise your output, for example, by inputting

`echo 'This is a sentence by ',$name,' which is fast';`

instead of

`echo 'This is a sentence by $name which is very inefficient';`

My basic example code is

```
$server=english
mysql_query("INSERT INTO uz(id,email,pw,cook) VALUES('$id','$mail','$pw','$cook')");
```

Which uses double quotes and var names inside of statements. Is there a way to optimise this or is it the "best" version? Every attempt I've tried resulted in mysql errors.

Comment: your second example won't work. Variables are only replaced in double quotes.

Comment: Unless you're running a facebook-sized operation, you will see absolutely NO difference between those strings. And if you are running facebook, you'll save maybe a few minutes of cpu time per year.

Comment: Time for PHP to parse that string 100s of nanoseconds, maybe some microseconds. MySQL query = dozens to hundreds of milliseconds (or possibly minutes!), depending on the dataset. Wrong end to optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

truthfully dealing in microseconds; surrounding variables in expanding strings with `{}` will save the parser a cycle or two and also cuts down on confusion between constants and associative array keys when used.

For Instance:

```
$string = 'hi ' . $name . ' how are you?'; //fast
$string = "hi $name how are you?"; //very slightly slower
$string = "hi {$name} how are you?"; //very slightly faster than second example

$string = 'hi ' . $person['name'] . ' how are you?'; //fast
$string = "hi $person[name] how are you?"; //slightly slower and prone constant clashes
$string = "hi {$person['name']} how are you?"; //very slightly faster and not prone to clashes
```

in the second example with an array key you can run into issues if there is a `const name` declared somewhere since the interpreter doesn't know which one you are referring two and uses the constant by default.

On the database side of things you can optimize your query by using "`"'s around your field and table names which both protects against keyword clashing and also allows for faster interpretation (still in microseconds).

For Instance:

```
mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`name`,`date` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = {$id}");
```

Comment: echo with commas does work. it means the strings are output with out concatenating first and it is ever so slightly faster then using dot to concatenate the strings prior to output. see manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 7):

**It does not matter.**

This kind of optimization has no real-life impact on your performance whatsoever. The performance differences between the various concatenation methods are in the microseconds. They play no real-world role at all.

Use what is most readable, and most in sync with your coding style, instead.

The same goes for the echo example you show. There is no measurable difference performance-wise unless you run it 100,000 times (in which case you would be something doing something wrong *anyway*). Do your own benchmarks using `microtime()` if you want to.

Comment: +1.  The big costs in querying are network overhead and waiting milliseconds or even seconds for mysql to respond -- a few nanoseconds of string interpolation is the least of your worries.